# Show that $M$ is isometric to a subset of $\ell_{\infty}(D)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

I just finished this problem from *N.L. Corothers'* real analysis book and believe I have the right idea, but finished the proof with the wrong conclusion. Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space.

> Let $D$ be dense in $M$. Show that $M$ is isometric to a subset of $\ell_{\infty}(D)$.

The **hint** is to use the following theorem: *Let $D$ be dense in $M$, let $N$ be complete, and let $f: D \to N$ be uniformly continuous. Then, $f$ extends uniquely to a uniformly continuous map $F: M \to N$, defined on all of $M$. Moreover, if $f$ is an isometry, then so is the extension $F$.*

---

let $f: D \to \ell_{\infty}(D)$ be given by $f(x) := (x,x,x,...)$ a constant sequence of $x$. Now since $f$ is uniformly continuous, $f$ is an isometry, and $\ell_{\infty}(D)$ is complete: by the given theorem $f$ extends uniquely to a uniformly continuous map $F: M \to \ell_{\infty}(D)$. Since $f$ is an isometry, so is $F$. Thus $M$ is isometric to $F(M) \subset \ell_{\infty}(D)$.

Is this correct? Any criticism is welcome.

Comment: I think $\ell_\infty(D)$ means the set of all bounded functions on $D$, that is $\phi : D \to \mathbb R$ with norm $\|\phi\| = \sup\{|f(d)| : d \in D\}$.  The definition should be earlier in the Carothers book.  If metric space $M$ is not separable, then $D$ must be uncountable in order to be dense.  But of course the most interesting consequence of this is where $M$ is separable and $D$ is countable, so $\ell_\infty(D)$ is the usual $\ell_\infty$ space.

Comment: @GEdgar After thinking about what you wrote, does this say anything more about the validity of my work? Even though I did not consider the norm on $\ell_\infty(D)$.

Comment: @TaylorRendon it says that you found isometric subset in some other space than $\ell_\infty(D)$.

Comment: @mihaild so my work as it stands right now is incorrect?

Comment: @TaylorRendon looks like so.

Comment: @mihaild - Do you have any suggestions for improvement in my work?

Comment: I think I can prove the statement (feel free to edit question or ask a new one if you are interested in it). I have no idea how to use the suggested hint.

Comment: @mihaild - Feel free to provide your answer underneath this question, the hint is optional. (:

Comment: Actually there was an error in my proof. However, I managed to find a better proof using provided hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose any point $x_0 \in D$. Define function $f_x(y)$, $x, y \in D$ as $f_x(y) = d(x, y) - d(x_0, y)$. From triangle inequality, $d(x, y) - d(x_0, y) \leq d(x_0, x)$ and thus $f_x$ is bounded, so in $\ell_\infty(D)$.

For $x_1, x_2 \in D$, $$|f_{x_1}(y) - f_{x_2}(y)| =\\ |d(x_1, y) - d(x_0, y) - d(x_2, y) + d(x_0, y)| =\\ |d(x_1, y) - d(x_2, y)| \leq\\ d(x_1, x_2)$$, so $\|f_{x_1} - f_{x_2}\| \leq d(x_1, x_2)$.
And $|f_{x_1}(x_1) - f_{x_2}(x_1)| = d(x_1, x_2)$. Combining, we get $\|f_{x_1} - f_{x_2}\| = d(x_1, x_2)$, so $F: D \to \ell_\infty(D)$, $F(x) = f_x$ is isometry. By theorem from hint, we can extend $F$ to isometry $M \to \ell_\infty(D)$.

Comment: What subset of $\ell_{\infty}(D)$ is $M$ isometric to?

Comment: Image of $M$ under this isometry (actually we can explicitly extend it, $F(x)(y) = d(x, y) - d(x_0, y)$ for $x \in M$, $y \in D$). I doubt there is a good description of this image.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, this was helpful.